# Possible to assign a class attribute that's a simple function python

Tags: python

I'd like to hold reference to callback functions in a singleton.
However, python does some magic (either at the point of assignment or at the point of calling), that means the function requires an instance object as the first parameter -- I want to be able to store a simple function. How can I do this?

Assigning to `X.__dict__` has the same effect.

```
def default(): print "default"

class X:
    func = None

    @staticmethod
    def setup(f=default):
        X.func = f

    @staticmethod
    def doit():
        if X.func is None: X.setup()
        # !!!!!!!
        # TypeError: unbound method g() must be called with X instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
        X.func()


def g(): print "g"
X.setup(g)
X.doit()
```

Comment: Why does `X` exist at all? Why did you define a class for this, especially if you're not going to make instances of the class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [storing unbound python functions in a class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327483/storing-unbound-python-functions-in-a-class-object)

Comment: And why are you using an old-style class? More to the point, why are you using Python 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

If you do :

`X.func()` after `X.setup()`. It won't work. The problem is with the setup function.

The first problem is your `f=default`. This syntax does not work in python. You cannot assign a variable to a default parameter.

Concerning your problem itself, what happen is that your class `X` does not "bound" with function g (or default).

You need

```
def default(): print "default"

class X:
    func = None

    @staticmethod
    def setup(f):
        if f is None:
            X.func = staticmethod(default)
        else:
            X.func = staticmethod(f)

    @staticmethod
    def doit():
        if X.func is None: X.setup()
        X.func()

def g(): print "g"
X.setup(g)
X.doit()
```

edit: **Use python 3 please**